# Multiple filters applied to a single list in Java 8+

Tags: java, list, arraylist, lambda, java-8

How can be achieved to pass a "list of filters" to a stream in Java 8, instead of applying them individually as illustrated in the following example?

https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/stream-multiple-filters-example/

The purpose would be to dynamically create a list of filters, one way would be to iterate through a list of filters and apply it to the list to be filtered.

Any other idea?

UPDATE:

Thanks for the comment of the predicate:

```
   final Predicate<?> predicate = new Predicate<?>() {

        @Override 
        public boolean test(Object object) {
            return false; //TODO: Implement first predicate
        }
    } ;

    predicate.and(...); //Implement another predicate.
```

Regards

~M

Comment: You can chain `Predicate`s using for example `Predicate::and` method.

Comment: True, I will try that, thanks for the comment.

Comment: As mentioned one can make one single Predicate consisting of a `.and` chain of predicates. However a chain of `.filter` has the same effect, as they are collected _before_ the final stream operation happens (collect/reduce/forEach).

Comment: True, however I would like to give admins an easy to understand solution on how to add more filters (predicates.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain predicates with either the `and` or `or` operator. Do you want your combined predicate to be a predicate that matches objects that match *all* the component predicates, or just at least one of them? If you want to simulate a chain of `filter` calls:

```
someStream.filter(...)
            .filter(...)
            .filter(...)
            .filter(...)
```

Then you should use `and`.

Depending on what you choose, you can use either of these methods:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> combineFilters(List<Predicate<T>> filters) {
    return filters.stream().reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(x -> true);
}

public static <T> Predicate<T> combineFilters(List<Predicate<T>> filters) {
    return filters.stream().reduce(Predicate::or).orElse(x -> false);
}
```

Usage:

```
someStream.filter(combineFilters(aListOfFilters))
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution indeed, in really chaining predicates for me would make sense only chaining all to "and" (for my particular problem)

Comment: A small correction for the `...reduce(Predicate::or)`, you have to use `x->false`.

Comment: @Aman Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Providing you have a predicate generator, like this test one

```
    Supplier<Integer> seed = () -> (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 2); // in [2, 11]
    Supplier<Predicate<Integer>> generator = () -> {
        int seedNow = seed.get();
        return (Integer value) -> (value % seedNow == 0);
    };
```

which, you know, provide a finite sequence of filters,

you'd better accumulate 'em before the actual filtering

```
    Predicate<Integer> cumulative = Stream.generate(generator)
            .limit(5)
            .reduce(Predicate::and).orElse((value) -> true);
```

and then exploit

```
    List<Integer> output = IntStream.range(0, 300)
            .boxed()
            .filter(cumulative)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,null,3,0,0,8);

   Predicate<Integer> fitlerPredicate = i -> i != null && i > 0;
    List<Integer> collect = numbers.stream().filter(fitlerPredicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
    collect.forEach(System.out::println);
```

you can chain a list of filter criterias using && operator and pass that value to filter operation of stream api